# Overlapping Tabbed Widget Layout

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-fragments, tabwidget

I'm having some issues with the layout below. In the Layout tool in Eclipse it shows fine, but when I open that fragment in the app all of the layouts, with the exception of  "indicatorName", that is everything in the tabbed, text view shows up as a overlapping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_indicatorName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Chart Fragment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="136dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="0" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/graphText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:text="Graph view"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#0000ff"
                        android:textSize="30dip" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tableText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:text="Table text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#0000ff"
                        android:textSize="30dip" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout posted above is the layout of a fragment that is included in a broader activity. However, I'm pretty certain that the above layout is the problem. I've also included the layout of the parent activity for good measure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/inlistFragment"
        android:layout_width="400dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="jm.org.data.area.IndicatorListFragment" >
    </fragment>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        >
<!--         android:background="@drawable/app_bg" -->

        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    />
                    <!-- android:background="@color/Grey" -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                     />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>

        <!-- <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is an example of text"
             /> -->

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/keywordFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="jm.org.data.area.KeywordsFragment"> 
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```